# Setting some header with current file name with Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to set a header, "CamelAwsS3Key", with the current file name, before uploading the file to Amazon S3, but I am not able to get the current file name, here is the Spring snippet:

```
...
<to uri="file:D:/camel_out?fileName=foo_$simple{date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.xml" />
<setHeader headerName="CamelAwsS3Key">
    <simple>${file:onlyname}</simple>
</setHeader>
<to uri="aws-s3://bucket?accessKey=xxx&amp;secretKey=yyy" />
```

Here is the message history (I removed useless columns):

```
...
[to2       ] [file:D:/camel_out?fileName=foo_$simple{date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.xml]  
[setHeader1] [setHeader[CamelAwsS3Key]                                           ]  
[to3       ] [aws-s3://bucket?accessKey=xxx&secretKey=xxxxxx                     ]
```

But the header is not set... From the log:

```
Exchange[
    ...
    Headers{... CamelAwsS3Key=null, CamelFileName=null, CamelFileNameProduced=D:\camel_out\foo_20150622124308.xml ...}
    ...
]
```

It works if I use a constant instead (the file is uploaded), like:

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelAwsS3Key">
    <constant>test</constant>
</setHeader>
```

How to set a header with the current file name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple `<simple>${file:onlyname}</simple>` is only when you consume from a file endpoint, eg from file.

To file producer (eg to file) only has one header which is file name produced:

- http://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html#line.125

which is also what you can see from your logs. You will need to write some code to extract only the name part of file named produced if you only want that, as the name currently includes paths. Though we could introduce a FILE_ONLYNAME_PRODUCED header in the camel file producer.

You are welcome to log such ENH request at: http://camel.apache.org/support